# Change value of parskip only for indented paragraphs

Tags: parskip

I'd like to have some vertical space between paragraphs, but both `\setlength\parskip` and the `parskip` package mess up the spacing for things like theorems and the title.

Is it possible to make Latex add vertical space only right before a paragraph that is normally indented?

Comment: you should use a class designed for that eg the koma script classes or the ntg classes. Basically at the level \parskip is activated everything is a paragraph, so you need to specify lengths for theorems and lists etc in the knowledge that parskip space is being applied, rather than take a class designed for zero parskip and make it all work when that is changed.

Comment: You could manually insert a \medskip everywhere needed.